# Converting &lt <xml> tag

Tags: java

I am using the following code

```
public String readXmlData() {
    ArrayList<String > list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String strLine = null;
    String finalText="";
    try{
        // Open the file that is the first 
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new  FileInputStream(path);

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            if(strLine.length()!=0){
                //list.add(strLine);
                finalText=finalText+strLine;
                System.out.println (finalText);

            }
        }
        System.out.println (finalText);
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return finalText;
}
```

The result it is giving is below:

```
&lt;center&gt;&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td bgcolor='#ffff00'&gt;Your Internet Order:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td colspan='2' bgcolor='#ffff00' align='right'&gt;test/test/test8&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td bgcolor='#ffff00'&gt;Description:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;EK Internet Booking Engine&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td align='right'&gt;1.00&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='2'&gt;Subtotal:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td align='right'&gt;935.65&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='2' bgcolor='#c0c0c0'&gt;Total cost:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td bgcolor='#c0c0c0' align='right'&gt;935.65&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='3'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td bgcolor='#ffff00' colspan='3'&gt;Your billing address:&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='3'&gt;&lt;br&gt;Address Object contains :
```

My requirement is that, I have to post xml as it is, in textbox.

Comment: Why are you using a [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) which has a very special purpose? Using it for simply reading a text file looks wrong.

Comment: Please suggests what should I use ?

Comment: Remove the `DataInputStream` and directly use the `FileInputStream`.

Comment: With FileInputStream also, I am getting the same problem

Comment: This was meant as a side note, not as an answer. That's why it is a comment.

Comment: To your question: It seems, your text file already contains those entity names. So there is nothing you can do now. Just replace them with their actual character.

Comment: To complete your question, you should add the content of the text file you are reading - only then, it is an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Call method unescapeXml(finalText).

```
public String unescapeXml(String escapedXml) {
    return escapedXml.replaceAll("&lt;", "<")
            .replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
}
```

Comment: It is not replacing

Comment: It is creating problem when there is <tag> under a <tag>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(myCode);`

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String)